# excel 2010 vba how can i declare a listbox?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, excel-2010

I have a userform which has the following bit of code included:

```
Private Sub RemoveRecipientCommandButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim intCount As Integer
    For intCount = RecipientsListBox.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If RecipientsListBox.Selected(intCount) Then RecipientsListBox.RemoveItem (intCount)
    Next intCount
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

This code is run on a listbox which is MultiSelect 1 - fmMultiSelectMulti, and works just fine. The problem comes when I try to allow parameters to be passed to it, so I can use the same sub on more than one ListBox. I've tried:

```
Private Sub RemoveRecipientCommandButton_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    RemoveSelected (RecipientsListBox)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

with

```
Private Sub RemoveSelected(LB As ListBox)
    Dim intCount As Integer
    For intCount = LB.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If LB.Selected(intCount) Then LB.RemoveItem (intCount)
    Next intCount
End Sub
```

I've also tried:

```
Private Sub RemoveSelected(LB As MSForms.ListBox)
```

and as

```
Private Sub RemoveSelected(LB As ListObject)
```

with the rest of the `RemoveSelected` code being the same. All of these forms of this code throw Error 424 - object required. I'm by no means an Excel pro, so my main concern here is just finding code that works - I want to be able to make this into something I can use on more than one ListBox, if necessary, without having to write the code as new for each ListBox. If someone could even point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

Comment: if you use `Private` for declaring Subs, they will need to be in the same module, or userform-module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple issues here.

1. Don't wrap parameters in parentheses calling `Sub`s without `Call`.
   So either `Call RemoveSelected(RecipientsListBox)` or `RemoveSelected RecipientsListBox`.
2. Default modus to hand over parameter is `ByRef` but that's not possible here. So using `ByVal`is needed.
3. Correct type is `MSForms.ListBox`

Code:

```
Private Sub RemoveRecipientCommandButton_Click()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 RemoveSelected RecipientsListBox
 'Call RemoveSelected(RecipientsListBox)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Private Sub RemoveSelected(ByVal LB As MSForms.ListBox)
 Dim intCount As Integer
 For intCount = LB.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If LB.Selected(intCount) Then LB.RemoveItem intCount
 Next intCount
End Sub
```

Edit:

As @Patrick Lepelletier stated, `ByRef` is possible in this case. I had the `Control` object stored in a local variable `Set oListboxControl = RecipientsListBox : RemoveSelected oListboxControl` what caused the problem with `ByRef`

So

```
Private Sub RemoveSelected(LB As MSForms.ListBox)
 Dim intCount As Integer
 For intCount = LB.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If LB.Selected(intCount) Then LB.RemoveItem intCount
 Next intCount
End Sub
```

will also work.

Comment: Why is a `Byref`not possible? I would definitely use a `Byref` in this situation, and i've done it many times.

Comment: On my phone right now so it's hard to compare the lines of code, but from what I can tell the only things I needed to correct was  msforms.listbox (which I tried) and either removing parentheses or using Call (which I didn't)? Thanks for the input everyone.